# Pass command to execute in function

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli

Sending command to run in bash function return the wrong result. I believe this is due to the `"` but not sure. Tried replacing the `$*` with `$@`, `$($1)` and `$1`.

```
#!/bin/bash

a(){

        status=unknown
        while [[ "$status" != "available" ]]; do
                aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier=qa-cls  --query "DBClusters[0]|Status"

                $* > /tmp/aaa.out
                #status=`$1`
                #status=$($1)
                #$@ > /tmp/aaa.out
                echo "$1"
                echo "$status"
                cat /tmp/aaa.out
                sleep 10

        done

}
aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier=qa-cls  --query "DBClusters[0]|Status"
a "aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier=qa-cls  --query \"DBClusters[0]|Status\""
```

returns:

```
available
available
aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier=qa-cls  --query "DBClusters[0]|Status"
unknown
None
```

Comment: Have you check just using `eval` to evaluate your command: ` eval "$*" > /tmp/aaa.out` ?

Comment: There's no need for `eval` here, it will only make things harder to work with and introduces further complications. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"$@"` in your function and remove the quotes from around the arguments passed to `a`:

```
a aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier=qa-cls --query "DBClusters[0]|Status"
```

The arguments to a function are an array, which is properly represented as `"$@"`. Without quotes (`$@` or `$*`) you'll get weird behavior (wordsplitting) and `"$*"` converts the array into a single string.

Some pointers:

- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices
- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays
- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting